# What are the DLC spells/characters, and how do I use them?

Tags: xbox-360, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I have purchased the two DLC packs for Lego Harry Potter Years 5-7 (The Xbox 360 version, if that's significant.)

Problem is, I can't actually *find* the spells or characters, having made the purchase.

Where should I be looking?

EDIT: I have now found [a list](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Harry_Potter:_Years_5-7#Downloadable_content) of the characters/spells offered in the DLC.  I checked the usual shops for the items to then buy them in game, but they do not seem to be amongst the stock for sale.  Nor do I seem just just have them automatically either.

Answer (score 2):

Although you have downloaded the characters and spells through DLC you will still need to "buy" them in-game through the relevant interfaces.

I believe the characters can be bought from the store called "Madam Malkins" in Diagon Alley.

The spells are bought from the "Bubbling Cauldron" shop in Diagon alley, I think, but I could be wrong.

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

I've done some further research and it appears that the spells are bought from a shop that is initially abandoned but becomes something else further into the game.

FURTHER EDIT:
Name of the shop is below as spoiler friendly - if you would like to see it, hover over.

> The Weasly Brothers Joke Shop

Comment: Rather than saying "I don't want to mention the name in case you haven't got that far in the game", You should include the name of the abandoned shop, just put it in spoilers.  Do so by adding `>!` to the beginning of the line you want to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I did see someone else do this on a post but wasn't sure how!  Updated as suggested.

Comment: No prob, im happy to help :) and welcome to Arqade!

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question - I have looked in both shops, and while all the base items are available there, the DLC items don't seem to be present, unless they're somewhere well hidden.

Comment: Ok, can I suggest you double check the DLC has actually downloaded? Go to Xbox dashboard > Settings > Storage > hard drive > Games and apps > Harry Potter Year 5-7 then see if the DLC is listed there?